# Angular.js - Changing an Element's CSS by clicking another Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-style

I'm very new to Angular.js.

I'm grabbing images from a MySQL database and printing them to the screen like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<div id='img_div' ng-click='popup()'>";
```

On the echoed div, I have an ng-click. In app.js, this is currently what I have for the ng-click (purely for testing purposes:

```
$scope.popup = function() {

// assign a message to the $scope
$scope.message = 'Hello World!';

// use the $log service to output the message in a console
$log.log($scope.message);
```

};

What I'd actually like to have in that ng-click function is:

```
modal.style.display = "block";
```

I'd basically like to set the CSS of another element.

Will I need to apply ng-style in order to do this?

Comment: in your case it could be just achievable by using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` directive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-style` with a `$scope` variable you can control the `display` property (or any for that matter):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.display = 'inline';
  $scope.setDisplayValue = function(value){
    $scope.display = value;
  }
});
```

```css
div#test {
  
  background: red;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="test" ng-style="{'display' : display}">{{display}}</div>
    <hr />
    <button ng-click="setDisplayValue('inline')">Set Display to inline</button>
    <button ng-click="setDisplayValue('block')">Set Display to block</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker mirror: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vR4SEnz7iX81CWIrShw

Comment: Thank you @couzzi , giving this a try now.

Comment: My pleasure. If it works for you, please mark this answer. :)

Comment: My apologies for the lateness on this. I tried to implement this as best as I could but am receiving "Unexpected End of Expression" errors. I have rewritten my echoed statement as: `echo "<div id='img_div' ng-click='setDisplayValue('block)'>";`

Comment: And the controller in my app.js `myApp.controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){
 
 $scope.display = 'none';
  $scope.setDisplayValue = function(value){
     $scope.display = value;
 };
}]);`

Comment: And the ng-style is on a modal window that is initially set to display: none: `<div id="myModal" class="modal" ng-style="{'display' : display}">{{display}}
     <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <span class="close">&times;</span>
       <img id="popup_img" src="#">
     </div>
  </div>`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting in comments..I will mark your answer and will continue to play with your code in hopes that I can get it to work for what I'm doing

Comment: provide a link to a plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net demo